# Area 51 login apparently requires the HTTP referer to be on

Tags: bug, area-51, login, user-accounts, privacy

I have a Mac on Mojave 10.14.6 (10.15 is newest) with Firefox 69.0.1 (according to Mozilla's website, the current release is 69.0.3).

I just tried to log in to Area 51, and got stuck on the page saying that it will redirect shortly for over a minute, before giving up.

I tried in my basically unmodified Chrome on a different account, and it did not get stuck. I thought about my settings, and remembered that I have the HTTP referer [sic] off.

I turned the referer back on, and *voila*, it works now! However, the referer is a horrible privacy risk—every time you click on a link, it sends the address the link was on over to the next page.

Please change this. With the referer off, logging in to all other Stack Exchange sites works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I also have HTTPS Everywhere, but I didn't turn that off.

Comment: Area51 is known not to work with HTTPS everywhere. There's another meta post on this issue somewhere IIRC

Comment: @Zoe yes, but HTTPS Security was still on and turning the referer back on seems to have made it work.